# Meteor cfs:gridfs Uploaded image with store is not rendering on server but works on local

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have setup meteor application on AWS server. I have used cfs:gridfs package for image uploading. Below is my code for that.

Images are getting uploded but when I am displaying them it does not render on server but works perfectly fine on localhost.

This is my image source
img src="/cfs/files/images/LquzjvKk4HmQRXP3v?store=thumbs"

If i remove store=thumbs from image source then it renders image. It's something related to the store that is causing the issue. I have checked the code and it is ok and works well on local. Below is my code.

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images");

var createThumb = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
  // Transform the image into a 59x45px thumbnail
  gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('59', 
 '45').stream().pipe(writeStream);
};

var createLogo = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
  // Transform the image into a 171x57px thumbnail
  gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('171', 
 '57').stream().pipe(writeStream);
};


Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
 stores: [
  imageStore,
    new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbs", { transformWrite: createThumb }),
    new FS.Store.GridFS("logos", { transformWrite: createLogo })
 ],
 'defaultPermission':true,
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I the found the issue. I moved to cfs:s3 and when i upload an image from my localhost everything works fine but the same thing when i upload from my production it actually uploads the image to s3 but the size over there is zero. I got the id and url in return but the file size is zero which mean there nothing to show/render.

Does anyone have an idea about this ?

Comment: I am using gm library to crop images which is not working on server. This is the reason images have size zero. For now i have skipped the cropping part and everything else is working fine.